# How to let the python script (abc.py) keep executing on AWS even after Connection lost or SSH connection is terminated?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was using `Jupyter notebook` on AWS AMI and using the port forwarding on Windows using `PuTTY`. I got my connection terminated and all the work of 24 hours is lost now and I'm unable to get that. So I used a script instead of Notebook and the same thing happened. I used to think that the process would keep going on even if the Shell connection is lost. But next time I login, I don't see anything.
I used `top`, `htop` `aux` to find if my processes are still running but they don't show my process. Please help how can I stop this from happening.

I am using Windows on 10 with `Putty` on local and `Ubuntu 18` on the AWS AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
nohup python3 myscript.py &
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: @Gary: Why is that `&` sign here? also, how can I connect to the same session the next time I want to connect?

Comment: @Deshwal `&` just runs it in the background so you can continue using your terminal. `nohup` prevents the program from exiting even if you exit the terminal. This method does not let you reconnect to the same session. If you are just tracking print statements you can redirect your outputs to a file using `nohup python3 myscript.py > log.txt &`. Then you can track your outputs by `tail -f log.txt`

Comment: I have already used logging in my script. my code creates new csv files, reads from them and even modify some files.  I just want to know that if that will be affected in any manner (except logging)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the tmux

```
apt install tmux
```

I often use it to keep my web runing on server(not professional but convenient）

Comment: How would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use screen.

You can install it wit:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

You can find more information right here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/